# Stripe webhook for when trial ends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm aware of the `customer.subscriptions.trial_will_end` event. It fires 3 days before a trial ends.

I couldn't find an event that actually fires when the trial is over and the customer hasn't paid. This would be useful to do something simple like this to turn off features:

`customer.update_attributes(active_account: false)`

Without a webhook like that, I'm looking at scheduling some tasks to check unconfirmed customers periodically and turn off features accordingly. The webhook seems cleaner though and less prone to errors on my side. Is there an event/webhook in line with these goals? FYI, customers don't have to put in a card when they start the trial - so autobilling is not an option.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When the trial period ends, there will be a `customer.subscription.updated` event and an `invoice.created` event. An hour (or so) later, you'll then either see an `invoice.payment_succeeded` event or an `invoice.payment_failed` event. From those, you'll know whether the payment went through or not.

Cheers,
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.

Comment: How can you tell if this is the first invoice for the subscription? If a user signs up for a free trial, never enters a credit card, and then the payment fails, it would be nice to treat it differently than a normal payment failed for an active user.

Comment: You can tell is the end of the trial when the `customer.subscription.updated` event has these attributes: `"previous_attributes" : { "status" : "trialing"...`

Comment: I don't see the "previous_attributes" field in the latest stripe documentation. https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscription_object,  has it been removed?

Comment: @VivekKothari It is in the `customer.subscription.updated` webhook, not `invoice.payment_failed`

Answer (score 16):

To add to Larry's answer and share how I got around the lack of a trial ended webhook, here's what I did.

In `invoice.payment_failed` webhook, I checked:

- Is this the first invoice since the subscription start?
- Does the customer have any cards saved?

If these checks fail, then I assume the trial has just ended with no billing details entered, and I cancel the subscription.

Example in Python:

```html
# get account from my database
account = models.account.get_one({ 'stripe.id': invoice['customer'] })

# get stripe customer and subscription
customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(account['stripe']['id'])
subscription = customer.subscriptions.retrieve(account['stripe']['subscription']['id'])

# perform checks
cards_count = customer['sources']['total_count']
now = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(invoice['date']))
trial_start = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(subscription['start']))
days_since = (now - trial_start).days

# cancel if 14 days since subscription start and no billing details added
if days_since == 14 and cards_count < 1:
  subscription.delete()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add 3 days to the free trial period and use the customer.subscriptions.trial_will_end event and update the subscription with 'trial_end=now'

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another way that can be handled easly. So `invoice.payment_failed` should be listened, in all `invoice` related events, inside `event.data.object`, there is `subscription id` or `subscription object`, you should get `subscription id` and retrieve `subscription` then you can get both `product id` and `price id`.
By `price id` or by `product id` you can know current subscription.